# typescript tagged union in generic

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

How to make this compile without errors? We are using TypeScript 2.9.1.

```
interface IFoo {
  type: 'foo';
  foo: string;
}

interface IBar {
  type: 'bar';
  bar: string;
}

type FooBar = IFoo | IBar;

class Getter<T extends FooBar> {
  private data: T;

  constructor(data: T) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public getMe(): string {
    const { data } = this;
    // Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'T'.
    // Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'T'.
    return data.type === 'foo' ? data.foo : data.bar;
  }
}
```

Comment: And what errors would those be exactly?

Comment: @musefan They are monioned in the comments of the source code directly above the affected line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler will not narrow variables that have the type of type parameter. You can type the variable explicitly and that will get the code to compile:

```
 public getMe(): string {
    const data :FooBar = this.data;
    return data.type === 'foo' ? data.foo : data.bar;
}
```

Comment: It looks like this [might](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/22348) get addressed in TypeScript 3.0.

Comment: @jcalz yup looks that way. I was trying to come up with why the narrowing would not be valid and I could not, looks like it was just an unimplemented feature.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir thanks for the answer. Unforunately my example was too much simplified from what I actually need. Could you help me with less simplified version at https://pastebin.com/dZvx9zSH? Do you think I should post it as separate question?

Comment: @MartinŽdila Sure, I can have a look, but I just left work so it won't be for a couple of hours...

Comment: @MartinŽdila sorry I only now got around to looking at your code, that will not work because the `xxx` and `data` are unrelated as far as the compiler is concerned. This is something you could try: https://pastebin.com/N6twzSsp